# How to efficiently preserve list of lists

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a relaxed json data of the form:
[ [ [a,b,c], [d,1,2] ], [ [x,y],[z,5,6] ], ....]] ]

What is the most efficient method to preserve this kind of list of list data structure? I am looking to use this in a dict format where the first element of each sublist is the dict key. Loading into pandas seems to distort the structure. Any recommendations are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion. Now that you mentioned ordereddict, if the sample data I provided above were to be preserved in a file, would it make sense to store that in a dictionary? Or better to load the list of lists first into dict and then ordereddict?

Comment: Depends on how you save it - if you want to save it as JSON objects - don't, JSON objects, just like Python dicts, are order-agnostic.

Comment: I think I do want to save it as JSON. Is there a way to store the above list of list of lists to a more strict JSON data structure?

Comment: JSON is not an ordered data structure by default so unless you control your reader and parser you cannot expect orderness from it. If you still insist on JSON, add the aforementioned `OrderedDict` as a hook to the internal `JSONDecoder` when reading: `json.JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)`

Comment: my use-case is to preserve the order as well as handle missing values and duplicate keys. For duplicate keys, I know defaultdict is a good datastructure selection, but unable to figure out how to generate an ordereddict from a dataset like this: [[['a', 2, 3], ['a', 1, 2], ['b', 5, 6]], [['x', 9], ['z', 5, 6], ['w']]]